Database Conflict in Multiple Docker Compose Setups
I have two LAMP stacks for each of my laravel app branches. Each branch is in a different folder. The setups run in a container with the following docker compose files:
1)
version: "3.1"
services:
    mysql:
        image: "mysql:8.0"
        command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
            - ".:/application"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
        ports:
            - "3306:${DB_PORT}"

    webserver:
        image: "nginx:alpine"
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ".:/application"
            - "./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    php-fpm:
        build: phpdocker/php-fpm
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ".:/application"
            - "./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini"
            - "./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-overrides.ini"
        env_file:
            - .env

volumes:
    mysql-data:



and 2)
version: "3.1"
services:
    mysql:
        image: "mysql:8.0"
        command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
            - ".:/application"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
        ports:
            - "3307:${DB_PORT}"

    webserver:
        image: "nginx:alpine"
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ".:/application"
            - "./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
        ports:
            - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
        build: phpdocker/php-fpm
        working_dir: /application
        volumes:
            - ".:/application"
            - "./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini"
            - "./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-overrides.ini"
        env_file:
            - .env

volumes:
    mysql-data:


I have basically only altered the external ports of mysql and nginx. The .env file is the same for both, and therefore variables like DB_PASSWORD, DB_USERNAME, DB_DATABASE are the same. I am using the same nginx configuration for both:
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

    root /application/public;
    index index.php;

    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        return 204;
    }
}

The problem is that whenever I am running my login API from the respective API-documentation webpages, which are http://localhost/api/documentation and http://localhost:8080/api/documentation, they both save the authentication token on the first mysql database. However, whenever I am manually using the login API from within the php-fpm docker container, through php tinker, the token is saved on the respective database. Why is this happening?
I have tried changing the names of my services, of the volumes, I have tried changing the database names, the credentials, I have even tried to define different networks for each docker compose so that they are isolated. Nothing worked.
